# Since I cant google this "#!" what exactly is it's use in the URL

Tags: url

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What's the shebang/hashbang (#!) in Facebook and new Twitter URLs for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3009380/whats-the-shebang-hashbang-in-facebook-and-new-twitter-urls-for)
>   [To hashbang or not to hashbang?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6756695/to-hashbang-or-not-to-hashbang)

Iv'e seen many sites using this hash in their URL and all I could figure out is that this is some way to monitor the users location in the site. Could anyone elaborate or point me in the direction of a good explanation?

Comment: See: http://code.google.com/web/ajaxcrawling/docs/getting-started.html

Comment: Google indexes `#!` (hash bang)

Answer (score 0):

Try googling for "hash-bang" instead of #!

Answer (score 0):

There is another topic on stackoverflow about this, but i couldn't find it right now.

Check this article http://code.google.com/web/ajaxcrawling/docs/getting-started.html

Answer (score 0):

It's called hashbang URLs. The idea is so that AJAXified website can be crawled by search engine, but it has a couple of drawbacks.

Comment: It has a couple of *major* drawbacks.

Comment: @Madmartigan: true, or [as Mike Davies puts it](http://isolani.co.uk/blog/javascript/BreakingTheWebWithHashBangs): `So the #! URL syntax was especially geared for sites that got the fundamental web development best practices horribly wrong, and gave them a lifeline to getting their content seen by Googlebot.`

Comment: ...or as [Ben Ward put it](http://developer.yahoo.com/blogs/ydn/posts/2010/10/how-many-users-have-javascript-disabled/#comment-17071): "If site content doesn't load through curl it's broken".